# Serialização de uma lista grande em JSON.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms

Pessoal estou com um problema para conseguir fazer a serialização de um objeto (uma lista de uma classe com aproximadamente 5000 itens).

estou usando o JSON.NET para gerar a string Json porém a mesma está ficando com o seguinte problema, no meio da mesma fica um texto assim:

```
,{"State":0,"DataAlteracao":null,"Id":0,"IdDadosRastreamento":0,"CodigoPeriferico":"0","ValorPeriferico":"0"}
,{"State":0,"DataAlteracao":null,"Id":0,"IdDadosRastreamento":0,"CodigoPeriferico":"0","ValorPeriferico":"0"}
,{"State":0,"DataAl:..."0","ValorPeriferico":"1840"}
,{"State":0,"DataAlteracao":null,"Id":0,"IdDadosRastreamento":0,"CodigoPeriferico":"0","ValorPeriferico":"1380"}
,{"State":0,"DataAlteracao":null,"Id":0,"IdDadosRastreamento":0,"CodigoPeriferico":"0","ValorPeriferico":"62"}
```

Observem em negrito que ele cortou o nome da tag bem como colocou "..." e depois seguiu criando normalmente o arquivo.

alguém sabe o que pode ser este problema e como posso resolver? o código para realizar a serialização é o seguinte:

```
string jsonReq = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

Onde request é a lista com 5000 posições.

Comment: Você está olhando diretamente para o resultado do `jsonReq` ou está tratando esta string depois? Também, este objeto request é o que? É uma lista de uma classe tipada ou você está usando um serializador interno na classe?

Comment: Rodrigo a jsonReq eu escrevo diretamente em um HttpWebRequest, o request é uma classe que tem duas propriedades AuthData: {} e uma listaPersistencia: [], que é o array que possui 5000 posições. 
O objetivo é realizar o consumo de uma api rest.

Comment: Pessoal descobri que o json na verdade está gerando normalmente, o problema está na transmissão via POST para a Url da API, o arquivo .json que está sendo gerado possui 12 megabytes, existe alguma configuração que tenho que fazer no app.config do winforms ou no web.config do asp.net ou no próprio IIS para poder fazer este post? o que vocês aconselham?

Comment: Olha eu não sei exatamente o porque o resultado é tão grande. O ideal seria você passar parâmetro de filtro ou no mínimo de paginação. Os resquests ideais não devem passar de alguns kb. O resto é paginado pelo cliente. Isto vai evitar muito timeout, tempo de servidor e, caso haja falhas, o cliente requisita somente a página necessária.

Comment: Rodrigo consegui localizar na doc da Microsoft a resolução, no meu caso esta lista não teria problemas em ser grande pois é uma transmissão via rede interna da empresa, é um serviço que fica obtendo os dados de rastreamento dos veículos, e insere em lote estes registros no banco

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pessoal consegui descobrir era devido o tamanho do POST que estava sendo feito, configurei o web.config conforme a documentação da Microsoft:

coloquei os seguintes itens adicionais no web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

e

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Esta é uma forma de contornar o problema. Mas sem filtros, ordenação e paginação você correrá o risco da aplicação cliente não conseguir todas as informações necessárias. Você também não conseguirá controlar o tempo de processamento do servidor. Se sua base tiver 1 milhão de registros, você vai processar todos eles só para o serializer jogar um pedaço fora. Enquanto definindo um tamanho máximo, você sabe que não vai demorar muito para ter o retorno, mesmo que seja necesário chamar o serviço mais vezes.

Comment: Essa resposta nao tem relacao com o problema. Mudar o limite do tamanho da mensagem de um HTTP Request nao em relacao com o resultado de serializacao. Por isso foi negativado.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentado, acredito que se você está retornando uma lista muito grande, o ideal é você adicionar em seu servidor as seguintes propriedades:

1. Receber variáveis para paginação: número da página solicitada, número de registros por página (o cliente pode especificar isso, mas no servidor você verificar se tanto o número da página começa com 1 e não passa do número de registros existentes e também que o número de registros por página não é maior que, por exemplo, 100 registros, ou algo que permita que o response não seja muito grande);
2. Estipular uma ordenação padrão mesmo que o cliente não tenha autoridade de perguntar por esta informação. Em geral, depende do contexto. Mas supondo que é uma lista incremental, pode ser legal ordenar por data descrescente. Se o cliente perguntar a primeira página com 100 registros, ele pega os 100 primeiros mais recentes. Aí se verficar que ele não tinha nenhuma destas informaçãos ele as usa, e daí passa para a página seguinte. Até chegar num registro que ele tem localmente. Daí ele não precisa perguntar pelas páginas anteriores. Em Geral esta abordagem faz mais sentido que começar da data mais antiga pra mais recente. Se a lista de retorno nunca for ordenada, seu cliente nunca poderá realizar esta operação.
3. Em geral é legal você adicionar estas informações com os `Headers` de resposta da sua requisição. Assim seu cliente pode verificar, por exemplo, que ele perguntou pelos primeiros 100 registros mas o servidor retornou que o `X-Record-Count` do response diz que existem 1 milhão de registros. Se a ideia é sempre paginar até o final, você terá ideia do quanto ainda falta pra terminar. Usando `Headers` também facilita ao não precisar encapsular o resultado num outro objeto com estas informações.